# How to force my iPhone application to stay in a specific orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Yes, I know this question has been asked a lot of times, but I can not find anything that helps me any further.

Using a navigation controller with 3 viewcontrollers, I need to retain the data from previous screens so I do not use segues but like this:

```
// When button is pressed
- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Skipped connection screen");
ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

}
where SecondView is the identifier of the view controller that should appear. Since I only want the rotation to be at horizontal right, I add this snippet of code at the top of every .m file I have for my views:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

return (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);  
}
```

and in my project-Info.plist I have added `Initial interface orientation = Landscape (right home button` and in my project settings I have added support for this orientation only.

The problem is that when running on the iPhone, the orientation changes from landscape if I turn my phone either way. When I try to turn it back it just wont. I would like to make sure this application is **never** able to rotate away from landscape right.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please see my below answer and let me know if you any issue with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you will add below key to your  .plist file then it will be fixed.

`"Supported interface orientations"`
Value of this key would be `"Landscape (right home button)"` or whatever you want so your application will support only that specified orientations.

Also add this code into every view controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);  
}
```

Comment: This, for app-wide, once-and-for-all fixed orientation. If you have a ton of different view controllers, this one liner is a no brainer.

Comment: I thought my project settings -> summary -> Supported device orientations had taken care of that, but appearently not. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use the argument in your 'return' code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
   return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much, that worked. Could you explain why it didn`t work  with my code?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen: your code was not working because you are using self.interfaceorientation. As far as i know self.interfaceorientation will get value after shouldAutorotate executed. Actually in ShouldAutorotate you have to compare received value in parameter from system and compare it with the orientation that you want to allow.